# Paypal parameters issue

Tags: paypal

In my original website files that connects to paypal checkout, I presently have an array:

> ```
> $fields = array(
>           self::ITEM_NAME => $order->get_description(),
>           self::ITEM_NUMBER => $order->get_id(),
>               );
> ```

That give me from database:

> Transaction Description
>
> Item number: 1000

How can I change the order of the array to give the following:

> Transaction Description #1000

I do not need to have the sentence "Item number". I just want to have the number following the Transaction Description.

In another words the get_id() variable must be after the get_description(),

Thaak you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue.

For somebody that might need the same situation here it is:

> self::ITEM_NAME => $order->get_description().' (Receipt#
>   '.$order->get_id().')',